# Upgrade to 14.10 messed up resolution

Tags: 14.10, intel-graphics, display-resolution

Upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 eliminated the 1920x1080 screen settings that were in use under 14.04. I use Intel graphics, no additional graphics card. Display is listed as 'Built-in Display', does not detect the type. Resolution is stuck at 1024x768. 
Have tried this:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -
hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode default 1920x1080
xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080
rebert@rebert-4790:~$ more xprofile
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode default 1920x1080
xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080
```

Which causes the 1920x1080 option to appear but generates error message when applied:

```
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1920, 1080), minimum=(1024, 768), maximum=(1024, 768)
```

Edit imported from non-answer:

```
root@rebert-4790:/home/rebert# cat fixres
#!/bin/bash

# run this script, 
# then select the appropriate display size in the display manager

# remove HD mode in case it exists
##xrandr --rmmode extHD &> /dev/null
##xrandr --rmmode extSD &> /dev/null

# add HD as additional mode
modeParam=$(cvt 1920 1080 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/r1920/')
echo "modeParam=$modeParam"
echo ""
xrandr --newmode $modeParam && xrandr --addmode VGA2 r1920
xrandr --newmode \"$(cvt 1366 768 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1366/')\" && xrandr --addmode VGA2 1366
xrandr --newmode \"$(cvt 1280 720 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1280/')\" && xrandr --addmode VGA2 1280
xrandr --newmode \"$(cvt 1024 576 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1024/')\" && xrandr --addmode VGA2 1024

Output:

root@rebert-4790:/home/rebert# ./fixres
modeParam=r1920  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

System is Intel 4790.

Results recently reported are using HDMI port. I haven't tried it on the DVI but in the past have gotten the same results on both. I understand that Intel graphics support disappeared from 14.10, is that correct? Is that the reason for these issues? I'll be less keen on doing upgrades in the future that are not to fix some specific problem, but would I be any better off with 15.04? Thanks for responses, been struggling with this for months.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# run this script, 
# then select the appropriate display size in the display manager

# remove HD mode in case it exists
##xrandr --rmmode extHD &> /dev/null
##xrandr --rmmode extSD &> /dev/null

# add HD as additional mode
modeParam=$(cvt 1920 1080 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/r1920/')
xrandr --newmode $modeParam && xrandr --addmode VGA2 r1920
#xrandr --newmode \"$(cvt 1366 768 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1366/')\" && xrandr --addmode VGA2 1366
#xrandr --newmode \"$(cvt 1280 720 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1280/')\" && xrandr --addmode VGA2 1280
#xrandr --newmode \"$(cvt 1024 576 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1024/')\" && xrandr --addmode VGA2 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the VGA adapter through a display port the system becomes unable to detect your resolution properly (don't ask me why). Try to use a DVI adapter instead, if possible.

Solved my problem when I got stuck with resolution issues.